# Displaying XSLT stylesheet table after header?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

EDIT: The table is working but it is displaying immediately to the right on my header instead of underneath like I would like it to. I've tried with two different browsers (Firefox and Chrome) and it is still not showing underneath. Is there anything I can do?

XML

```
<bbgame>
  <gametracker gameid="1288244"></gametracker>
  <venue gameid="GAME11"
           visid="MSU" visname="MISSOURI STATE"
           homeid="LOU" homename="LOUISVILLE"
           date="12/17/2013" location="KFC Yum! Center, Louisville, KY"
           time="9:05PM" attend="21335" schednote="" start="" end="" duration=""
           leaguegame="N" neutralgame="N" postseason="N">
</venue>
</bbame>
```

XSLT

```
    My Code so Far.... <xsl:template match="//bbgame"> 
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Official Basketball Box Score -- Game Totals</h1>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="//venue/@visname"/> vs. </td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="//venue/@homename"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
    </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is what I am seeing as output.. 
Official Basketball Box Score -- Game TotalsMISSOURI STATE vs. LOUISVILLE

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to use XSLT to transform an XML document into an HTML document that has a table?

Comment: You are closing your `<gametracker>` tag twice.

Comment: @ColinD Yes sir. I am practicing because I have a huge document to work with. I would like a table with the two different teams underneath the heading "Official Basketball Box Score".

Comment: @Zzyrk Sorry I will fix that. I accidentally entered that because I was trying to show a sample of the large XML file I am working with. EDIT: I have removed the double closing tag. Sorry for the confusion. My XML file is about 20 pages and this is just a sample I am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML input is not well-formed.

- You close the `gametracker` element too early.
- `</bbame>` should of course read `</bbgame>`

These kinds of errors are usually detected by XSLT processors and most browsers.

With this input:

```
<bbgame>
  <gametracker gameid="1288244">
  <venue gameid="GAME11"
           visid="MSU" visname="MISSOURI STATE"
           homeid="LOU" homename="LOUISVILLE"
           date="12/17/2013" location="KFC Yum! Center, Louisville, KY"
           time="9:05PM" attend="21335" schednote="" start="" end="" duration=""
           leaguegame="N" neutralgame="N" postseason="N">
</venue>
</gametracker>
</bbgame>
```

Your transformation works fine, you get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Official Basketball Box Score -- Game Totals</h1>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>MISSOURI STATE vs. </td>
            <td>LOUISVILLE</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Beyond answering your question, I feel duty-bound to note that your XSLT code could do with a bit of improvement. For instance, avoid matching elements with `//` since this retrieves elements regardless of where they are in the tree.

Comment: Thanks I have fixed that poorly formatted XML. Is there a way to move this table so it appears underneath the Heading and not directly to the right of it. As of now I am seeing.        Official Basketball Box Score -- Game TotalsMISSOURI STATE vs. LOUISVILLE

Comment: When I view it with Firefox, the table is shown underneath the heading. What do you mean? It would be best to explain this in terms of: _how should the HTML output change_ to meet your expectations? Edit your original post.

Comment: I have edited my original question. Thank you for your suggestion. I tried opening this in Firefox as well as Chrome and it is still not displaying underneath. Can I style with CSS to make sure it is properly located? I also appreciate your comments on my XSLT code. I am still learning and need to adjust the code so it is a little more eloquent.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour, so I'm not sure I can help you any further. But yes, you can influence the positioning of a table in HTML. Maybe you should post another question that asks exactly for this? (Also, if this answer was helpful to you, consider accepting it - mark the tick on the left).

Comment: I have checked it as acceptable. I guess some more time spent learning XSLT is needed. Maybe in a couple days once I've obtained some more knowledge and worked on the code I might ask another question. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You're welcome. You can expect the best answers if you show your entire XSLT code (you left out a part of yours), together with your XMl input and, crucially, the HTML output you get - and say in what way this differs from what you expected.

Comment: <xsl:output method="text"/> This was what was causing the problem I believe. Once I removed it I was able to see the positioning. I somehow left this out of the original code. Thanks so much for your help again.